# Multiple relations in Yii 2.0 ActiveRecord Model

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-model

I am trying to define relations in ActiveRecord Model Class, but the problem is our database is too large and has many relations. So is there a simpler way to declare relation in only one model so that Yii can understand the relation for every other model it is related to.

```
public function getBill_details()
{
    return $this->hasMany(bill_details::className(),['company_bill_id'=>'id']);
}

public function getCompany()
{
    return $this->hasOne(company::className(),['merchant_c_id'=>'id']);
}
```

I have created two functions for two relations. Similarily I have around 80 relations in one table only so is there an simpler way of doing it.

Comment: use `gii` to generate model.

Comment: but how gii will help in defining relations. How it will now what relations are??

Comment: you must give relation of 'fk' in database tables then gii will generate relation for them.

Comment: 80 relations in a table? seriously?

Comment: Gii will create all relations automatically, assuming you have proper foreign keys defined. I bet you don't, though ;)

Comment: 80 relationships in a table suggests a bad DB design! Or an absolutely epic app... Can you autogenerate an entity relationship diagram of your DB?

Answer (score 0):

If you could use innoDB and set the relations on the database before Gii generates the models, Gii would generate the models with the relations for all tables.

Answer (score 0):

You can use gii extension to generate the relations [gii](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/ext-gii-index.html)